# viewing XML data if attribute value equals variable value

Tags: php, xml, sorting

I'm stuck on something extremely simple.

Here is my xml feed:
http://xml.betfred.com/Horse-Racing-Daily.xml

Here is my code

```
    <?php
function HRList5($viewbets) {
$xmlData = 'http://xml.betfred.com/Horse-Racing-Daily.xml';
$xml = simplexml_load_file($xmlData);
$curdate = date('d/m/Y');
$new_array = array();


foreach ($xml->event as $event) {
    if($event->bettype->attributes()->bettypeid == $viewbets){//$_GET['evid']){
//  $eventid = $_GET['eventid'];

//    if ($limit == $c) {
//        break;
//    }
//    $c++;
    $eventd = substr($event->attributes()->{'date'},6,2);
    $eventm = substr($event->attributes()->{'date'},4,2);
    $eventy = substr($event->attributes()->{'date'},0,4);
    $eventt = $event->attributes()->{'time'};
    $eventid = $event->attributes()->{'eventid'};
    $betname = $event->bettype->bet->attributes()->{'name'};
    $bettypeid = $event->bettype->attributes()->{'bettypeid'};
    $betprice = $event->bettype->bet->attributes()->{'price'};
    $betid = $event->bettype->bet->attributes()->{'id'};
    $new_array[$betname.$betid] = array(
    'betname' => $betname,
        'viewbets' => $viewbets,
        'betid' => $betid,
        'betname' => $betname,
        'betprice' => $betprice,
        'betpriceid' => $event->bettype->attributes()->{'betid'},
    );
}

ksort($new_array);
$limit = 10;
$c = 0;
foreach ($new_array as $event_time => $event_data) {


//  $racedate = $event_data['eventy'].$event_data['eventm'].$event_data['eventd'];
    $today = date('Ymd');

    //if($today == $racedate){
    //  if ($limit == $c) {
    //    break;
    //}
    //$c++;



    $replace = array("/"," ");
//  $eventname = str_replace($replace,'-', $event_data['eventname']);
    //$venue = str_replace($replace,'-', $event_data['venue']);
    echo "<div class=\"units-row unit-100\">
    <div class=\"unit-20\" style=\"margin-left:0px;\">
".$event_data['betprice']."
</div>
<div class=\"unit-50\">
".$event_data['betname'].' - '.$event_data['betprice']."
</div>

<div class=\"unit-20\">
<a href=\"horse-racing/race/\" style=\"text-decoration:none;\"><img src=\"betnow.gif\" ></a><br />
</div>
</div>";
    }

}//echo "<a href=\"horse-racing\" style=\"text-decoration:none; line-height:25px;\"><strong>View ALL Horse Races</strong> <strong>&gt;&gt;</strong></a>";
//var_dump($event_data);
}
?>
```

Now basically the XML file contains a list of horse races that are happening today.
The page I call the function on also declares

```
<?php $viewbets = $_GET['EVID'];?>
```

Then where the function is called I have

```
<?php HRList5($viewbets);?>
```

I've just had a play around and now it displays the data in the first `<bet>` node
but the issue is it's not displaying them ALL, its just repeating the 1st one down the page.

I basically need the xml feed queried & if the event->bettype->attributes()->{'bettypeid'} == $viewbets I want the bet nodes repeated down the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't use `simplexml` so can offer no guidance with that - I would say however that to find the elements and attributes you need within the xml feed that you ought to use an `XPath` query. The following code will hopefully be of use in that respect, it probably has an easy translation into `simplexml` methods.

***Edit:*** Rather than targeting each bet as the original xpath did which then caused issues, the following should be more useful. It targets the `bettype` and then processes the childnodes.

```
/* The `eid` to search for in the DOM document */
$eid=25573360.20;

/* create the DOM object & load the xml */
$dom=new DOMDocument;
$dom->load( 'http://xml.betfred.com/Horse-Racing-Daily.xml' );

/* Create a new XPath object */
$xp=new DOMXPath( $dom );
/* Search the DOM for nodes with particular attribute - bettypeid - use number function from XSLT to test */
$oCol=$xp->query('//event/bettype[ number( @bettypeid )="'.$eid.'" ]');

/* If the query was successful there should be a nodelist object to work with */
if( $oCol ){
    foreach( $oCol as $node ) {
        echo '
            <h1>'.$node->parentNode->getAttribute('name').'</h1>
            <h2>'.date('D, j F, Y',strtotime($node->getAttribute('bet-start-date'))).'</h2>';

        foreach( $node->childNodes as $bet ){
            echo "<div>Name: {$bet->getAttribute('name')} ID: {$bet->getAttribute('id')} Price: {$bet->getAttribute('price')}</div>";   
        }
    }
} else {
    echo 'XPath query failed';  
}

$dom = $xp = $col = null;
```

Comment: It works, thanks, however how can I get it to just display the attribute value i specify eg name / price / id ?

Comment: Rather than iterate through the entire attribute collection just target the ones you want

Comment: thanks, its displaying all data however for some strange reason its displaying each item 7 times before displaying the next

Comment: forgot to // the foreach statement lol
works perfectly ! Many thanks !!1

Comment: The XPath query targets the `bet` node - it could be changed to target the `bettype` node instead and then you would iterate through the `childNodes` collection. Anyway, glad it helped - hopefully you can make use of the code :)

Comment: How can I display the event @name value ? event is the top level element

Comment: when i use echo $meetingtitle = $event->getAttribute('time').' - '.$event->getAttribute('meeting').' - '.$event->getAttribute('name');  it repeats down the page & I cant find out where to place it so it only displays that data once

Comment: IGNORE - Fixed , had to pass data along in URL from previous page & stroe in var & call